# FindById Redis return null object

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-jpa

I am using Redis as a database for some data that I need fast access and when I'm trying to get the saved object, I'm always getting null as a result. When using KEYS *, the data is present so it means that the save operation works correctly.

I'm using Spring Data with CrudRepository. To get the object I'm using findById() which is not working. Below I attached all info needed.

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
    redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

My class:

```
@RedisHash("LostUser")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class LostUser implements Serializable {
    @Indexed
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String email;

    @TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    private Long expirationTime;
 }
```

I have read every question related to this topic. I changed the configs, I added @Indexed as provided in another question, ensured that the data is present in the database. Any suggestion can help.

Thanks!

Comment: can you check what type of query it's sending to Redis using debugger or MONITOR command?

Comment: Hi, I have this query: "HGETALL" "LostUser:6615bdb3-b0ca-4350-ad4e-7c2fa250d8c8" . Where LostUser is the class name and that long String is the id. But the result is still null.